# Xcode simulate subsequent app launch after initial app installation on Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I am trying to get debug logs from Simulator for subsequent app launches after initial app installation. This means running the app on Xcode, quitting the app and launching it again on Simulator.

However, quitting the app would cause the debugger to stop running. How do I get logs while running the app on Simulator but not through Xcode?

Comment: Why can't you just relaunch from Xcode?

Comment: What debug logs are you referring to? What APIs are you using for the logging?

Comment: @HangarRash doesn't relaunching from Xcode install the app into the simulator again?

Comment: @HangarRash I'm using print statements to see if a certain view controller has been loaded from app delegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Comment: Yes, relaunching from Xcode will build and install again. Not sure how that affects what you need to check. If you quit the app (really quit, not just return to the home screen) then starting the app again with or without Xcode will result in the same code path being run.

Comment: But would that behaviour be the same in a real iOS device? Would the same code path be run if I start the app, quit the app and start again?

Comment: Yes, if the app is fully quit (killed) and restarted, it would be the same.